# How to change the background color for layouts using configuration file in android

Tags: java, android

I want to change the background color for layouts dynamically for the first time only, using configuration file in android that file should be in assets folder,it can be xml file or anything.
please help me.

Comment: Can you post something that you have tried..?

Answer (score 0):

If you set an ID to your layout as follows :

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/myLayout">
<LinearLayout/>
```

Then you can set your backGround in onCreate like this:

```
myLayout= findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.use color for int value.
in the assets file config.txt, you can input color for int value like this. for example this value is Color.RED

```
4294901760
```

2.use this code in your appliaction

```
        String config = "config.txt";
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = getAssets().open(config);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        String color = dis.readUTF();
        ColorDrawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(Integer.parseInt(color));
        //use drawable
        //for example
        new TextView(this).setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(color));
        new TextView(this).setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(is != null)
        {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

3.you can use reflect, but in the config file, write the color name from values/colors.xml.

```
        String config = "config.txt";
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = getAssets().open(config);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        String color = dis.readUTF();

        try {
            Field field = R.color.class.getDeclaredField(color);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Integer id = (Integer) field.get(null);

            ColorDrawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(id));
            // use drawable
            // for example
            new TextView(this).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(id));
            new TextView(this).setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Damet,how can I add the color code in config.txt,can u send an example for that adding the colors to the config.txt file

Comment: you know, IO stream must be in pairs. you can use notepad application,  but in this way, you must keep only color in every line.so i suggest that you should make an application to control your config files.if you need,please post your email to me.